# Does Mongoose.JS countDocuments() validate filters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, code-injection

Does the MongooseJS function `Model.countDocuments()` validate the filters being used? or is it subject to injection attacks with unsafe inputs?

For example,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    job_title: String
})

var Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema)

Test.countDocuments({ job_title: request.body.manager_search })
    .then((result) => { console.log("result: ", result) })
    .catch((err) => { console.log("Error counting documents: ", err) })
```

Is this code introducing an injection vector, or will the `request.body.manager_search` be cast to a string by this function?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't validate and no cast to `String`.

Mongoose calls native MongoDB collection method `countDocuments(query, options)`

If `query` contains injection vector (like `job_title: {'$ne':''}`, [see restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#countdocuments-restrictions)), MongoDB *will not prevent injections in your app*

**Example:**

```
{ job_title:  'foo'  }
result:  2

{ job_title:  { '$ne': '' }  }
result:  3
```

**Solution:**

Tricky solution: `{ job_title: {$in:[request.body.manager_search] } }`
Tricky solution2: `{ job_title: request.body.manager_search + "" }`
Mongo-sanitize: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize

Comment: OK that was my concern.  How should I prevent injections for this type of query? Should I manually attempt to cast the input to a String before calling the `countDocuments()` function?  I'm new to mongoose, but I was expecting more robust injection protection, as from my past experience with MySQL libraries which basically eliminate injection vectors with parameterized queries, etc.

Comment: Updated my response, please check again

Comment: Got it. So the only way to inject is with variables beginning with $ character?

Comment: Yes. If the value starts `{...}`, means injection